# Can Typekit fonts be used by ABCPdf to Create PDFs?

Tags: abcpdf, typekit

We are not getting Typekit fonts which are used in our website for Creating PDFs using WebSuperGoo - ABCPdf.
Is there are way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Such usage, even if it could be made to work, would be explicitly against Typekit's [reason for existing](http://blog.typekit.com/2009/05/27/introducing-typekit/):

> That’s where Typekit comes in. We’ve been working with foundries to develop a consistent **web-only font linking license**. We’ve built a technology platform that lets us to host both free and commercial fonts in a way that is incredibly fast, smoothes out differences in how browsers handle type, and offers the level of protection that type designers need without resorting to annoying and ineffective DRM.